# Drag and drop not working after installing my program

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, nsis

I have a c# winforms app that I have written which uses drag and drop to accept files. Running it from Visual Studio works fine, and if I manually copy the files to a folder it has no problems. I have an installer script that I have created to package it for distribution using NSIS.

After installing to my own system using the installer, drag and drop **does not work**. Everything else about the app runs **fine**.

Is there some sort of security thing I might be missing here?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Drag-and-drop typically does not require admin rights to install/register or operate say if your app is acting as a _drop target for files dropped from Windows Explorer_.  Could you explain more of what your app is meant to do?

Comment: What does (the all bolded) **does not work** mean?  There's a lot to drag and drop (the visual effects, etc. as well as the "something has been dropped on me" events).  Does any part of drag and drop work?  Are you doing a full-bore install of your app or a Click-Once install?  What you really want to do is create an [mcve]; recreate a minimalist version of your program with just the feature that doesn't work.  Show us your code.  Describe how the installer works and what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UAC UIPI blocks dragging from a low/medium IL process to a elevated process.

The easy solution is to just disable the run checkbox on the finish page in your installer. This forces the user to start your app normally from the start menu.

Another solution is to [whitelist the drag messages](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-for-an-elevated-mfc-application-on-vistawindows-7/) to allow the drag operation.